# maven eclipse checkstyle plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, checkstyle

I have custom checkstyle checks file (called checks.xml), and I'm trying to use that same file in both maven and eclipse. It all works well, except for the `SuppressionFilter`.

In this checks.xml file, I have

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="src/main/resources/checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>    
</module>
```

This works when I run through maven. However, when I run through eclipse, I need to change the config to be

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${basedir}/src/main/resources/checkstyle/checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>    
</module>
```

If I run with the ${basedir} property with maven though, I get the error that property ${basedir} has not been set.

Is there a way use this same configuration file in both maven and eclipse? I feel like there should be, but I'm just missing something on how to properly populate the suppression filter.

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: I think my suggestion was just irrelevant and I removed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure there is a way to use the same configuration file in both maven and eclipse but it requires a little setup first. I wrote a blog post on how to achieve this even for a multi-module maven project. see: [maven-checkstyle-and-eclipse](http://jgonian.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/maven-checkstyle-and-eclipse/)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your blog post was so clear and fixed a problem I had spent too long researching.

Answer (score 8):

This is hell. Eclipse and Maven handle suppressions different and don't share variables.
Derived from [Rolf Engelhard](http://rolf-engelhard.de/?p=46)

So in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.8</version>
   <configuration>
     <propertyExpansion>config_loc=${basedir}/src/main/checkstyle</propertyExpansion>
     <configLocation>${basedir}/src/main/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
      <suppressionsLocation>${basedir}/src/main/checkstyle/suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
     <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <phase>verify</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>check</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Now in checkstyle.xml (${config_log} is an Eclipse specific thing, but by specifying it in the pom we make it available to maven as well):

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
  <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/suppressions.xml" />
</module>
```

And if you're using `maven-site-plugin` or any other plugins that also rely on CheckStyle don't forget to update those to have the config_loc property as well (or declare it global to the pom, though I wasn't able to get this to work properly).

Answer (score 1):

`<propertyExpansion>basedir=${session.executionRootDirectory}</propertyExpansion>` works for me, but only when added to the `<plugin>`node, not to `<execution>`!

`project.basedir` does not work well in multi-module projects, because it will point to the submodule folder instead of the root folder.

Answer (score -2):

You could try defining `${basedir}` as a property in your pom.
See the [pom reference quick overview](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Quick_Overview).

```
<property>
          <name>basedir</name>
          <value>${project.basedir}</value>
</property>
```

Comment: basedir is already a maven property. I have added a propertyExpansion tag to the maven checkstyle configuration that says <propertyExpansion>basedir=${basedir}</propertyExpansion> and that seems to do the trick. It seems a little odd that I would need to do this though.

Comment: @Jeff - That 1 line has ended two days of misery for me. Thanks a ton!