# maven eclipse with m2e: suppression in multi module project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I can't get eclipse-cs to use the suppressions.xml. I use the m2e-code-quality plugin.

The checkstyle.xml and suppressions.xml are in their own (aggregated/non-child) module:

```
-parent
|-build-tools
||-pom.xml
||-src.main.resources.checkstyle
| |-checkstyle.xml
| |-suppressions.xml
|-pom.xml
|-core
|-utils
|-...
```

The build-tools pom is minimal, no dependency.
The other (child)modules don't have any checkstyle dependencies or files.
From the (EDIT: parent-) pom:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.16</version>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
   <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
   <version>6.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>{groupId}</groupId>
   <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
   <version>{version}</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <configuration>
  <configLocation>checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
  <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle/suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
  <propertyExpansion>checkstyle.suppressions.file=${checkstyle.suppressions.file}</propertyExpansion>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And from the checkstyle.xml:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
 <property name="file" value="${checkstyle.suppressions.file}" />
</module>
```

The maven build works fine.

Some time back I got the suppressions to work even for eclipse when I had the checkstyle and suppressions files in each module, but I couldn't get it to work for centralized files.
I read all questions I could find, i.e. [maven eclipse checkstyle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981673/maven-eclipse-checkstyle-plugin/4480217#4480217), links therein..

Comment: Have you tried the `<propertyExpansion>basedir=${basedir}</propertyExpansion>` trick mentioned in one of the comments in the question you link?

Comment: That worked for the distributed files, but it won't for the centralized, since basedir is module specific. I also tried `${basedir}/../build-tools/etc` but that didn't work either. Besides: that solution would be hierarchy-dependent, and the idea of mavens dependency management is to be independent of such things.