# Checkstyle XML implementation using Maven

Tags: java, maven, build, code-formatting, checkstyle

I am trying to have Checkstyle XML implementation in to my project. I have below included in my `pom.xml` and I have my `checkstyle-checker.xml` in the same location as my project.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
<configuration>
<configLocation>checkstyle-checker.xml</configLocation>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
"-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.1//EN"
"http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_1.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
<module name="TreeWalker">
<module name="EmptyBlock">
<property name="option" value="stmt" />
<property name="severity" value="error" />
<property name="tokens"
value="LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_WHILE, STATIC_INIT" />
</module>

<module name="EmptyBlock">
<property name="option" value="text" />
<property name="severity" value="error" />
<property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_CATCH" />
</module>

<module name="MissingSwitchDefault">
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="StringLiteralEquality">
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="JavadocStyle">
<property name="checkEmptyJavadoc" value="false" />
<property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false" />
<property name="checkHtml" value="true" />
<property name="scope" value="private" />
<property name="severity" value="error" />
<property name="tokens"
value="INTERFACE_DEF, CLASS_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF" />
</module>

<module name="ConstantName">
<property name="format" value="^[A-Z](_?[A-Z0-9]+)*$" />
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="MemberName">
<property name="applyToPackage" value="true" />
<property name="applyToPrivate" value="true" />
<property name="applyToProtected" value="true" />
<property name="applyToPublic" value="true" />
<property name="format" value="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
<property name="severity" value="warning" />
</module>

<module name="MethodName">
<property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="ParameterName">
<property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="TypeName">
<property name="format" value="^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
<property name="severity" value="error" />
<property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF" />
</module>

<module name="NeedBraces">
<property name="tokens"
value="LITERAL_DO, LITERAL_ELSE, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_FOR, LITERAL_WHILE" />
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="RedundantImport">
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn">
<property name="severity" value="warning" />
</module>

<module name="UnusedImports">
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="ModifierOrder">
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

<module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations">
<property name="severity" value="error" />
</module>

</module>

<module name="SuppressionFilter">
<property name="file" value="${basedir}/suppressions.xml" />
</module>

</module>
```

When I ran `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` I am getting below error. It would be helpful if someone can assist on what is missing.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:checkstyle (default-cli) on project automation-dev: An error has occurred in Checkstyle report generation. Failed during checkstyle execution: Failed during checkstyle configuration: unable to parse configuration stream: Property ${basedir} has not been set -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Could you post your `checkstyle-checker.xml` file? Also, where is it located in your project?

Comment: Updated with checkstyle-checker.xml. This file is same location as my pom.xml

Comment: @Tunaki. Thanks for your reference it was able to fix this by removing <module name="SuppressionFilter">
<property name="file" value="${basedir}/suppressions.xml" />
</module>.

Comment: Refer also to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3981673/1743880

Answer (score 2):

@Tunaki. Thanks for your reference i was able to fix this by removing:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
  <property name="file" value="${basedir}/suppressions.xml" />
</module>
```

Reference ${basedir}/suppressions.xml was causing problem in parsing checkstyle-checker.xml as this was non-existent. As an immediate fix i removed it. This can be included as needed when there are specific files that needs to suppressed from checking

Comment: No need to downvote any longer. Just a (now corrected) formatting problem. :)

Comment: Could you also add an explanation as to why this fixed the problem?